# How to update DataGridView after inserting data into database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

Here is a code I use to insert data into the database.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=stroibot-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=OOP6;Integrated Security=True")) 
{
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Collection (ID, Color, Width, Height) VALUES (@ID, @Color, @Width, @Height)");
      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
      cmd.Connection = connection;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", GetID());
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", GetColor());
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Width", GetWidth());
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", GetHeight());
      connection.Open();
      try {
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
     catch(SqlException) 
     {
        ClearDataBase();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }

      connection.Close();
}
```

After this nothing is showing up in my datagridview (yes, there is data in the database itself). If I close application and open it again then the data will appear, but come on, I do not want to close app just to see data.

I tried updating it using Update() and refreshing using Refresh() but nothing helped.

So what do I need to do to somehow show data I just uploaded in my database?
Thank you!

P.S. WinForms

**Edit #1**: I also tried to null datasource and then reinitialize it again.

**Edit #2**: Here's everything related to database

```
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.colorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.widthDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.heightDataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.collectionBindingSource;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(353, 18);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(443, 401);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ID";
        this.iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "ID";
        this.iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // colorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.colorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Color";
        this.colorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Color";
        this.colorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "colorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // widthDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.widthDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Width";
        this.widthDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Width";
        this.widthDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "widthDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // heightDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.heightDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Height";
        this.heightDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Height";
        this.heightDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "heightDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // collectionBindingSource
        // 
        this.collectionBindingSource.DataMember = "Collection";
        this.collectionBindingSource.DataSource = this.oOP6DataSet;
        // 
        // oOP6DataSet
        // 
        this.oOP6DataSet.DataSetName = "OOP6DataSet";
        this.oOP6DataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
        // 
        // collectionTableAdapter
        // 
        this.collectionTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
```

Comment: How is your `DataGridView` connectected to your Database? What happens if you simply run the code you use during loading the application again?

Comment: how do you bind your `DataGridView` ? plz provide the code

Comment: The code that I posted?

Comment: Added code about datagridview

Comment: call your select function again?

Comment: I don't have select function